# webcontents.send no envia mensajes a Html

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, electron

estoy realizando una aplicación de escritorio con "Electron", el cual debe enviar un objeto el cual contiene información de una base de datos, el cual le asigna a variables los datos de la primera fila de la base de datos y se lo envie a el documento HTML, pero el problema es que no sé el documento .js no está enviando el objeto, o si mi documento html no está escuchando lo que se le envía, mi codigo de la aplicación js es el siguiente:

```
let mainWindows

const {app, BrowserWindow, ipcRenderer, ipcMain  } =  require('electron');
const mysql =  require('mysql');
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '241522qQ',
    database: 'Basededatos_Rad'
});

app.on('ready', () => {

    mainWindows = new BrowserWindow({
        webPreferences:{
            nodeIntegration:true,
            nodeIntegrationInWorker:true
        }
    });
    mainWindows.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/index.html`)
}); 

connection.connect(function(err) {
    // in case of error
    if(err){
        console.log(err.code);
        console.log(err.fatal);
    }
});

let query = 'SELECT * FROM trabajadores';
connection.query(query,function(err,rows,fields){
    if(err){
        console.log("Error al hacer la consulta");
        console.log(err.fatal);
        return
    }
    let Row = {
        Nombre: rows[0].Nombre,
        Apellido: rows[0].Apellido,
        Rut: rows[0].Rut,
        Area: rows[0].Area,
        HorasPedidas: rows[0].Volumen_de_horas,
        Eliminado: rows[0].Eliminado
    }

    mainWindows.webContents.send('Prueba1',Row);
    console.log(Row);
})

connection.end(function(){

})
```

y mi codigo HTML es el siguiente:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Registro de asistencia digital</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const { electron } = require('electron');
        const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

        ipcRenderer.on('Prueba1',(e,row) => {
            console.log(row);
        });
    </script>
    <img src="Canvas/3.png">
    </body>
</html>
```

Por ende necesito saber porque el codigo html no está escuchando lo que el codigo .js debería enviar, o el problema es que el codigo .js no está enviando el objeto.